# Inequalities involving determinants and minors of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, determinant

Lately I've been dealing with positive definite matrices in my research (in the context of them being covariance matrices), and, am wondering if anyone knows of a comprehensive list of inequalities involving determinants and minors of these matrices.

I have Horn and Johnson's "Matrix Analysis" which has proofs of the basic inequalities in Chapter 7.8 (s.t. Hadamard's, Fischer's, Szasz's, Minkowski's, and others), and found [this article](http://www.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/paper86.pdf) by the esteemed duo of Cover and Thomas to be helpful (they prove the above inequalities using information theoretic tools, and provide a few other ones derived using that machinery).

Unless the above is it (which I doubt), a comprehensive list would be very useful.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but maybe you find this hint useful nonetheless: since you are also interested in minors you possibly may want to have a look at Trudinger and Lin's paper 'On some inequalities for elementary symmetric functions', Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. Vol. 50 (1994) [317-326].